# How can I pass the item.id into the swipeButtons?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to pass the id from the current item to the function to delete it.

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useLayoutEffect } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput, Image, ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";
import { FlatList, TouchableOpacity, Directions } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { AntDesign, Ionicons, Feather } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import firebase from "../firebase"
import { AuthContext } from "../AuthNavigator";
import Swipeout from "react-native-swipeout";

console.disableYellowBox = true;

export default function Ingredients() {
  
  //In this Function i want to get the id from the Item to pass it into the function to delete the item


  const swipeButtons = [
    {
      text: <AntDesign name="delete" size={24} color="black" />,
      backgroundColor: '#AD1457',
      onPress: () => handleRemoveItem(index)
    }
  ]



  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    < Swipeout
      autoClose
      right={swipeButtons}
      backgroundColor="transparent"
    >
      <View style={styles.item} >
        <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", marginTop: 5 }} >
          <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: item.image }}></Image>
          <Text style={{ color: '#fff', marginTop: 5, marginLeft: 50, fontSize: 18 }}>Menge</Text>
          <Text style={{ color: '#fff', marginTop: 35, marginLeft: -30, fontSize: 18 }}>{item.amount}</Text>
          <Text style={{ color: '#fff', marginTop: 10, marginLeft: 80, fontSize: 22 }}>{item.label}</Text>
        </View>
      </View >
    </Swipeout >
  )



  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState('');

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.searchBar}>
        <View style={{ alignSelf: "flex-end", marginTop: 8, marginRight: 30 }}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => fetchIngredient(searchValue)}>
            {!isLoading && <Ionicons name="md-add" size={32} color="#fff" />}
          </TouchableOpacity>
          {isLoading && <ActivityIndicator style={styles.loading} color='#AD1457' />}
        </View>
        {!isLoading && <TextInput style={{
          alignSelf: "flex-start", marginLeft: 25, marginTop: -30, fontSize: 20, color: '#fff', width: 200
        }} placeholder="Suche" placeholderTextColor='#fff' value={searchValue} onChangeText={(searchValue) => setSearchValue(searchValue)}></TextInput>}

      </View>

      <FlatList
        data={userIngredientsList}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}>
      </FlatList>
    </View >
  );
}
```

I need to pass it into the `swipeButtons` function, to pass it into the `handleRemoveItem` function and delete the item from the list. It would be nice if you give me some good ideas and not only short answers.
I'm new to react and don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of directly using an array use it as a function and pass the Id or whatever the property you need.

```
const swipeButtons =(id)=> [
    {
      text: <AntDesign name="delete" size={24} color="black" />,
      backgroundColor: '#AD1457',
      onPress: () => handleRemoveItem(id)
    }
  ]

const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    const buttons = swipeButtons(item.id);
    return (
    < Swipeout
      autoClose
      right={buttons}
      backgroundColor="transparent"
    >
      <View style={styles.item} >
        <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", marginTop: 5 }} >
          <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: item.image }}></Image>
          <Text style={{ color: '#fff', marginTop: 5, marginLeft: 50, fontSize: 18 }}>Menge</Text>
          <Text style={{ color: '#fff', marginTop: 35, marginLeft: -30, fontSize: 18 }}>{item.amount}</Text>
          <Text style={{ color: '#fff', marginTop: 10, marginLeft: 80, fontSize: 22 }}>{item.label}</Text>
        </View>
      </View >
    </Swipeout >
  );
  }
```

Comment: i get an error buttons.map is not a function ( in 'buttons.map(this._renderButton)',

Comment: For some reason its not calling the function from assignment, try out the updated answer

Comment: ill get the same error as before, also the swipe does not push my view away like it does in all tutorial, do you know why?

Comment: i get an error buttons.map is not a function ( in 'buttons.map(this._renderButton)', still this one

Comment: Did you try the updated answer ? with the render function ?

Comment: I tried this and it works and shows the icon when swiped right

Comment: but can you say me why it does not push the view to the left ? its overlapps the view

Comment: I think you should check your styles

Comment: which one could the reason for it ?

Comment: Easiest way to find out is to remove components and adding one by one, its hard to tell by looking

Comment: I tried your style and dont see any issue, i can swipe and see the icon

Comment: yeah but the icon is over the list item i want it to push the item to the left

Comment: didnt get you, the image on the left us getting hidden and the icon is displayed

Comment: when slide i see still the image and the button is before the label text, im running it on iphone

Comment: I dont see a problem in the code or styles that you have shared,better check other components in the screen

Answer (score 0):

```
< Swipeout
  autoClose
  right={swipeButtons(index)}
  backgroundColor="transparent"
>

const swipeButtons = ({index}) =
{
  text: <AntDesign name="delete" size={24} color="black" />,
  backgroundColor: '#AD1457',
  onPress: () => handleRemoveItem(index)
}
```

I'm not familliar with functional components but this way must works